# Bash or Bourne Scripts?

Tags: bash, scripting, sh

Is it better practice to write Bash scripts or Bourne scripts?  My team writes Bourne scripts but I am not entirely sure why.

If this is a holy war question (ie: vim vs. emacs) please just reply: holy war.

Comment: just so long as it isn't csh

Comment: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: REAL programmers code in Korn! :-P

I always prefer sh compared to bash, because most of the syntactic/feature stuff will be the same or at least compatible with sh behaviour in most distros; whereas bash just isn't available in some cases if you work with AIX etc. But if you're working with Linux-only scripts, bash is preferable. Makes for a lot easier programming imho.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on what your target platform is.

If you're only targeting, say, major Linux distributions and Mac OS X, then you can be confident that these systems will have bash available. On other UNIXes (e.g., AIX, Solaris, HP-UX), bash may not necessarily be present, so Bourne is the safer choice. If bash is available, I can think of no reason you might prefer Bourne.

Answer (score 12):

You can be more sure that Bourne shell will be installed on any given Unix computer.  Yeah, Bash is ubiquitous on Linux, but the whole world isn't Linux.

Comment: Somewhat along those lines, I can think of only three reasons: backward compatibility, portability, or "that's the way we've always done it."

Comment: "Bash is ubiquitous on Linux, but the whole world isn't Linux." This was my belief before, then i started working with Solaris and HP-UX machines. I thought i could write shell scripts in Bash for these machines, oh how wrong I was. But it was a good humble learning experience, now I always use the bourne shell and only syntax that I know is POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 11):

The most important thing is to remember that not every OS softlinks /bin/sh to /bin/bash, as some Linux distros do. A lot of scripts are written for bash but begin with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

so that they break e.g. in Ubuntu. So, when you write bash script, always write:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: One of my cow orkers was mad at Ubuntu because they used something other than bash for /bin/sh.  I told him he should be mad at the idiots who mislabeled their bash scripts as sh scripts, but he wouldn't agree with me.

Comment: No, you should always write `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Bash might be installed at /bin/bash on your machine, but that's non-standardized and non-universal. If you stick to `#!/bin/sh`, however, you'll probably be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Well, is a matter of taste, but for starters, bourne shell scripts can be run with bash, and I think bash has features that cannot be run by Bourne.

Answer (score 2):

I use Bash as my login shell, but for scripting I'd choose the Bourne shell any day of the week and twice on Sunday. Bash has better features, better user friendliness and better bugs.

Actually, the same stuff that makes me choose Bash when I'm logging in, makes me avoid it when scripting. Bash tries to make everything nice and cozy for the user, but at the expense of a 776 kB executable (on my machine), compared to 140 kB for Bourne shell. Why would my script care about user friendliness? Any gain I might achieve through the use of some clever Bash function is effectively cancelled out by the shell footprint, which is more than five times as big.

I have computers running Linux, FreeBSD and OS X. Although I rarely move anything between the computers, it's nice to have the possibility. In a Bourne shell script, you simply type

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and it just works. Always. Bash might be common on Linux, but it's not as standardized as the Bourne shell. On FreeBSD, Bash is not installed by default. It can be installed from Ports if the sysadmin thinks it's a good idea but, even then, it ends up in **/usr/local/bin/bash** (not **/bin/bash**). Thus, if you still decide to go with Bash, you should write

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

to make the script portable. `env` will find the shell for you, regardless of your Unix flavor (as long as it's installed).

At the end of the day, it's your choice. Just make sure that your scripts are actually *compliant* to the shell you choose, and not relying on "sh" being symlinked to "bash" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Portability.  I write `#!/bin/sh` unless things get really to painful, and then I write `#!/bin/bash`.  The world is changing very rapidly, and I'm betting that in the future it will be easy to convince sysadmins to install bash.  But I hedge my bets by using Bourne for most stuff, which is simple.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X /bin/sh is NOT a Bourne shell. (But you may get a true bournesh over at freshmeat).

To identify a traditional Bourne shell you may try to use the circumflex ^ (caret) as a replacement for | (pipe).

See:

The Traditional Bourne Shell Family,

http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for bourne again shell, as the bourne shell can be slightly different among unix implementations. With `bash` you can be sure that `bash` is always `bash`.

Comment: I wouldn't say that different shells operate differently. Any shell I know will fall back to bourne shell behavior if it is started as `sh`

Comment: I have seen different bourne shell (sh) implementations that behave differently. Maybe this is not the case anymore.

Comment: "With bash you can be sure that bash is always bash." Unless it's a different version of Bash. There are obviously significant differences between major version numbers, but there are also some between minor version numbers.

Comment: ...but you're right that Bourne (at least what passes for it) can be "more different".